# same case value but run different formula if first character is

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a renaming script and all is working unless I have a specific file name. Which is common in every project.

I am renaming file names based on the file length. I have 2 file lengths that are both = to 12 but need to be named differently. Can I have an if statement inside of that one case to see if the first Character is `=0,c,e"`?

```
Sub Convert()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim val As String
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each aCell In rng.Cells
Select Case Len(aCell)
    Case 12
        If val = Left(aCell, 1) = "0" Or "c" Or "e" Then 'Example: 01730101.pdf = S-173-0101.pdf
        val = "S-" & Mid(aCell, 2, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 8)
        Else 'Example: 173d0071.pdf = S-173-D7.pdf
        val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 8)
        End If
    Case 13 'Example: 173d00710.pdf = S-173-D7.pdf
        val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
    Case 15 'Example: 173d170c071.pdf = SD-170-C7.pdf
        val = "SD-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 15) & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 12) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 12)
    Case 16 'Example: REF-173d0071.pdf = REF-173-D7.pdf
        val = Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & (Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 12))
    Case 17 'Example: REF173d00710.pdf = REF-173-D7.pdf
        val = Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & (Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 13))
On Error GoTo whoa
    Case Else
        val = "_Mod " & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 4)
End Select

val = UCase(val)

val = val & " " & aCell.Offset(, 2) & aCell.Offset(, 3)

aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = val
Next
Call RemoveZero
Call RemoveBadChar
    Range("C1").Select
    Worksheets("Rename").Columns("B").AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
whoa:
MsgBox "Please delete any empty rows."
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thx for any help

Comment: Yes you can actually. Everything looks OK to me - are you having an issue?

Comment: @DougCoats I get a `Type mismatch, runtime error 13`  on the line after `Case 12`

Comment: You cannot have 2 equals sign on the same line, this is the reason for the error

Comment: @MattTaylor The extra equal signs is the exact issue

Comment: @Lowpar It is the use of the `Or` operator on the `String` variables which will be causing the error - the rest of the line would just cause **very** unexpected results.  (Pedantically, you **can** have two equals signs, e.g. `If x = y = 5 Or 4 Then` is perfectly fine, as it is equivalent to `If ((x = y) = 5) Or 4) Then`, which will always be treated as `True` because `x = y` will be either `True` or `False`, but both `True` (-1) and `False` (0) are not equal to 5 so `x=y=5` will be `False`, and `False Or 4` gives `4` which is non-zero and therefore `True`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Convert()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim val As String, check
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each aCell In rng.Cells
Select Case Len(aCell)
    Case 12
        'I added a check here
        check = Left(aCell, 1)
        If check = "0" Or check = "c" Or check = "e" Then  'Example: 01730101.pdf = S-173-0101.pdf
        val = "S-" & Mid(aCell, 2, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 8)
        Else 'Example: 173d0071.pdf = S-173-D7.pdf
        val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 8)
        End If
        check = ""
    Case 13 'Example: 173d00710.pdf = S-173-D7.pdf
        val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
    Case 15 'Example: 173d170c071.pdf = SD-170-C7.pdf
        val = "SD-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 15) & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 12) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 12)
    Case 16 'Example: REF-173d0071.pdf = REF-173-D7.pdf
        val = Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & (Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 12))
    Case 17 'Example: REF173d00710.pdf = REF-173-D7.pdf
        val = Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & (Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 13))
On Error GoTo whoa
    Case Else
        val = "_Mod " & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 4)
End Select

val = UCase(val)

val = val & " " & aCell.Offset(, 2) & aCell.Offset(, 3)

aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = val
Next
Call RemoveZero
Call RemoveBadChar
    Range("C1").Select
    Worksheets("Rename").Columns("B").AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
whoa:
MsgBox "Please delete any empty rows."
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```